# How to run scripts outside the main web directory effectively? 

Tags: php, apache, vhosts, apache2.2

I have Web-Developer Server Suite, with PHP 5.25, which I downloaded from SourceForge.
My operating system is Windows 7 Home Edition.

I upgraded Apache to the latest version and will be upgrading PHP to 5.38 soon.

It works well, apart from one small problem; virtual hosts outside the main webroot
(C:/www/vhosts) ***do not*** display PHP scripts, or indeed any scripts at all; just the plain code. All virtualhosts work within C:/www/vhosts, but not any of the other locations I've declared in vhosts.

The other locations are:

- C:/www/
- C:/www/vhosts-test/
- C:/www/businessweb/
- C:/www/newmediasite/public_html/

This is despite the fact I declared the locations in httpd-vhosts.conf !

How would I get the server to understand PHP outside the main webroot, and also ASP.NET

(bear in mind I added mod_aspdotnet as well).

I'd gladly appreciate any advice on this; just spent a day-and-a-half rebuilding my webserver, moving files from a backup (all PHP and MySQL) after reinstalling Web-Developer Server Suite (which, IMHO, is pretty good for a beginner).

I'm not sure where to go with this, but I'll add, just for relevance, that this is strictly a development server for testing.

Comment: You need to configure modules/(f)cgi action handlers for each virtual host IIRC. In any case you can actually configure it per virtual host. That would also allow you to use different PHP versions in parallel if you need that.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your scripts in protected directory outside your Webroot so they are not accessible by your visitors.

However you need to place a script in your Webroot, that include these scripts. Most of the Firmwares implement a similar functionality.

```
<?php
 require_once('/var/usr/myConfigDir/config.php');
?>
```

As I understand, only the directory configured as Webroot will be able to execute scripts. Already Apache adds a security layer for not executing scripts outside Webroot.

So if your target is to protect some of your scripts, you can do that, otherwise, I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, you want to be able to have your PHP files anywhere on your computer, yet have them still be able to execute. I do not believe this is possible, as PHP files are opened through the webserver i.e 127.0.0.1/foo.php instead of file://foo.php/

The webserver is configured to execute the files in /www, unless there is a setting somewhere (which I am unaware of) all PHP scripts will have to rest in /www.

Comment: Not quite that way; just within the C:/www/ directory, basically.